# Can this code be changed to run faster?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, random, compile, distributions

I've worked for several days trying to get this code to run faster. The imported data is 15MB.

```
    cyclesperday = 
  CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/heaneym/\
cyclesperday"];
nc = 10^5;
AbsoluteTiming[
 samplemanycyclesper5years = 
  ParallelTable[Total[RandomChoice[cyclesperday, 1826]], {100*nc}];
 cycledatatofit = Partition[samplemanycyclesper5years, 100];
 samplecycledistributions = 
  ParallelTable[
   EstimatedDistribution[cycledatatofit[[i]], 
    LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]], {i, 1, nc}];
 cyclesamples = 
  Round[ParallelTable[
    RandomVariate[samplecycledistributions[[j]]], {j, 1, nc}]];
 ]
```

The above code takes about 110 sec to run.

Here is the code revised as suggested below:

```
cyclesperday = 
  CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/heaneym/\
cyclesperday"];
nc = 10^5;
rand = Compile[{{cycl, _Real, 1}, {i, _Integer, 0}}, 
   Module[{pos = RandomInteger[{1, Length[cycl]}, i]}, 
    Total[cycl[[pos]]]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
maxLikelihood = 
  Compile[{{values, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{\[Mu] = Mean[Log[values]]}, {\[Mu], 
     Sqrt@Mean[(Log[values] - \[Mu])^2]}], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
AbsoluteTiming[
 samplemanycyclesper5years = rand[cyclesperday, Array[1826 &, 100*nc]];
 cycledatatofit = Partition[samplemanycyclesper5years, 100];
 samplecycledistributions = maxLikelihood[cycledatatofit];
 cyclesamples = 
  Round[ParallelTable[
    RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution @@ parms], {parms, 
     samplecycledistributions}]];
 ]
```

The above revised code takes about 107 sec to run.

How can the different components of the code be significantly faster (see below), but the components put together not be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm concentrating on the calculation of `samplemanycyclesper5years` and `samplecycledistributions`. For the first one, you select 1826 samples randomly and calculate the total. This is done `10^7` times. We can pack the random total into a compiled function that chooses 1826 random integer positions, accesses `cyclesperday` and calculates the total

```
rand = Compile[{{cycl, _Real, 1}, {i, _Integer, 0}},
   Module[{pos = RandomInteger[{1, Length[cycl]}, i]},
     Total[cycl[[pos]]]
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

The parameter `i` is how many random values of `cycl` should be totaled. In your case *always* 1826. Let's test this

```
rand[cyclesperday, Array[1826 &, 10^5]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.921493, Null} *)
```

and compare

```
ParallelTable[Total[RandomChoice[cyclesperday, 1826]], {10^5}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {5.89441, Null} *)
```

So this needs only 15% of the time your `ParallelTable` needs. The next step is to do the same for the estimation of the `LogNormalDistribution`. The estimation of the parameters is [actually very simple](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2927&context=etd) with a maximum likelihood estimator and you can write this down yourself

```
maxLikelihood = Compile[{{values, _Real, 1}},
  Module[{μ = Mean[Log[values]]},
   {μ, Sqrt@Mean[(Log[values] - μ)^2]}
   ],
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True
]
```

First a quick check:

```
EstimatedDistribution[cycledatatofit[[10]], 
 LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
(* LogNormalDistribution[7.42205, 0.042639] *)

maxLikelihood[cycledatatofit[[10]]]
(* {7.42205, 0.042639} *)
```

Excellent. Now let's time it

```
samplecycledistributions = 
   ParallelTable[EstimatedDistribution[cycledatatofit[[i]], 
     LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]], {i, 1, nc}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {15.8202, Null} *)
```

and

```
maxLikelihood[cycledatatofit]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.167895, Null} *)
```

So this needs only 1% of the original time. Your complete calculation looks like this

```
nc = 10^5;
samplemanycyclesper5years = 
 rand[cyclesperday, Array[1826 &, 100*nc]];
cycledatatofit = Partition[samplemanycyclesper5years, 100];
samplecycledistributions = maxLikelihood[cycledatatofit];
cyclesamples = 
 Round[ParallelTable[
   RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution @@ parms], {parms, 
    samplecycledistributions}]];
```

and I was able to bring it from 654 seconds to 53 seconds. I checked the final histograms and they match perfectly, but please verify each step yourself.

Comment: That is incredibly helpful! How can I learn how to do what you did?

Comment: It takes some experience because simply throwing `ParallelXXX` into the code rarely works. Usually, I have a hunch which parts can be improved. In your case, I saw that the things you do in parallel are rather small computations and the highlevel approach with `ParallelTable` might be improved by only using thread-parallelization and not kernel-parallelization. For the estimation, I knew how Max-Likelihood worked and I guessed that the formulas for your distribution are possibly rather easy and can be compiled. What really helps is when you have at least a clue how you would write functions..

Comment: like `EstimatedDistribution` if you wouldn't have the whole machinery of Mathematica. And then you need to be persistent until you really understood why something is slow and if you can improve it. This takes time that I have already investigated when hitting problems myself, but it is nothing you cannot learn. If you like home-work for the upcoming weekend: Why don't you try to apply the same approach to the last slow `RandomVariate` part of your code? It is not as easy as my examples, but you would gain a lot of understanding.

Comment: Sadly, it would probably take me months of work to get good at it, and my work project doesn't allow that time. I'll try to learn it as I go along.

Comment: I am comparing the run times of the two nb's, and they are about the same. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Process `cyclesperday` thus:

```
cyclesperday = Developer`ToPackedArray[cyclesperday, Real];
```

Your data gets loaded as a mix of `Real` and `Integer` values.  To take best advantage of the CPU, the data should all be of the same type and in a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).  The second argument causes the integer values to be converted to `Real`.

Then the rest of the code takes about 150 sec. to run.  (I cannot tell you how long the original takes on my computer, because it ran out of memory.  Packed arrays save memory, too.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I now use it to store my data.

Comment: If the data were all integers, would it be faster to store it as integers?

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney On most machines, integers and reals are 64 bits, so it should take the same amount of time to ship the data out to a device (if that's what you mean by "to store it"). If you're converting to some data format, then I'm not really sure which is faster to convert. It may depend on the format chosen. To compute with the data, just to cover another base, at least with the Intel i7, the throughput is nearly the same.  Integers may be a little faster, except when dividing(!); and they overflow sooner.